# Change Text in Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following list:

```
    var submenu = localStorage.getItem('SubMenu')
    var submenuList = submenu.split(',');

0: "Ownership"
1: "Skills<br>Dev"
2: "Financing<br/>and ESD"
3: "Socio-Economic<br>Dev"
4: "Access to<br/>Financial Services"
5: "Board Participation"
6: "Employee Structure"
7: "Preferential Procurement"
8: "Enterprise Development"
9: "Supplier Development"
```

What I want to do is write a `forEach` statement in Javascript to replace some certain words with my own hard coded work. For example, where `Dev` appears I want to change it to `Development` and where `Financing<br/>and ESD` I want to change it to `Empowerment Financing`

I tried the `replace` method of my list but that gives me errors because i am getting confused with my `forEach` statement

This is what i have tried

```
submenuList.forEach(word =>{allMenuItems = allMenuItems.replace('Dev','Development')})
```

Comment: Hey Mohammed, in order to answer your question, we need the fragment of the code that you run and that ends up throwing an exception. It is hard to reproduce the an issue in code if there is no code.

Comment: use an object inside replace like replace('dev',obj['dev']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't allow you to modify each element like that. Put simply, the `word` value in your handler is just a value, not a reference to the item in the array. You can either use a for loop to actually get a reference to each element in the array (not recommended), or you can use `map` to modify each word instead.

```js
submenuList = submenuList.map(
  word => word.replace(
    'Dev',
    'Development'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

`replace()` method return new replaced string, not actual replace on the source string, so you should use `map` instead of `forEach` because `map` will take all of the output and return them in new array.

And also, because you want to replace every occurence of `'Dev'` or `'Financing<br/>and ESD'`, you should use `replace` with [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) flag. Replace by string pattern will only replace first occurence.

Example code:

```js
var submenu = localStorage.getItem('SubMenu')
var submenuList = submenu.split(',');
var result = submenuList.map(element => element.replace(/Dev/g, 'Development').replace(/Financing<br\/>and ESD/g, 'Empowerment Financing'));
```

---

**Improvement**:

You should replace the string before do `split`. So you don't need to `forEach` or `map` and improve performance.

Example code:

```js
var submenu = localStorage.getItem('SubMenu')
var replacedSubmenu = submenu.replace(/Dev/g, 'Development').replace(/Financing<br\/>and ESD/g, 'Empowerment Financing');
var result = replacedSubmenu.split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [
 "Ownership",
 "Skills<br>Dev",
 "Financing<br/>and ESD",
 "Socio-Economic<br>Dev",
 "Access to<br/>Financial Services",
 "Board Participation",
 "Employee Structure",
 "Preferential Procurement",
 "Enterprise Development",
 "Supplier Development"
]

const newArr = [];

for(let item of arr) {
  if(item.endsWith("Dev")) {
    console.log("Dev found");
    newArr.push(item.replace("Dev", "Development"));
  } else {
    newArr.push(item);
  }
}

console.dir(newArr);
```